Finde css selector with Capybara on a Tailwind pseudo class name
Let say I have a radio button styled with Tailwind class
<input type="radio" class="bg-red-500" checked="checked"/>

I can find the element with Capybara's matchers
expect(page).to have_selector(".bg-red-500")

However how would I find an emement styled with Tailwind's pseudo element class names?
<input type="radio" class="checked:bg-red-500" checked="checked"/>

this doesn't work:
expect(page).to have_selector(".checked:bg-red-500")
expect(page).to have_selector(".checked\:bg-red-500")
expect(page).to have_selector("checked\:.bg-red-500")


Maybe just add a class that has some kind of semantical value instead? Referencing classes which are just glorified inline styling in your tests just seems very brittle.

these are ViewComponent tests using previews. I'm testing if given component renders certain properties of component for different variants

Well turns out double quotes are to blame :)  ...more percisly interpolation of "\:"
This doesn't work 
expect(comp).to have_selector(".checked\:tw-bg-primary-600")

but this does work 
expect(comp).to have_selector('.checked\:tw-bg-primary-600')

or
expect(comp).to have_selector(%q(.checked\:tw-bg-primary-600))

